# Short story about a romance during a nuclear crisis; title was possibly "I Remember"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for a short story I read probably 50 years ago, which had an ongoing refrain "I remember ... " about a romance that occurs while a nuclear crisis gradually builds up and finally the bomb is dropped.

The title may have been along the lines of "I Remember"

Comment: Off to a good start, with great details, could you possibly outline in a little more depth what exactly made it science fictional or fantastic?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

["I Remember, Anita"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?95415), a short story by [Langdon Jones](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/jones_langdon); first published in [*New Worlds SF* #144, September-October 1964](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?181149+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/New_Worlds_144v48_1964-09-10#page/n69). Does any of [these covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?95415) ring a bell?

> I remember, Anita, when I first saw you. The cosy, cossetted Scottish village of Aberfoyle; the wild cragginess of the mountains round, and the little humanity of the hotel, sitting like a stone in its mountain setting.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> I remember that I thought nothing more of you than as a particularly desirable woman; but even purely as that, I was quite obsessed by you after the first evening I saw you.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> I remember, Anita, the third walk we had.
>
> [. . . . . . . . . .]
>
> I remember how I was sitting at home, quietly reading. Then the flash, the flash. Oh, Oh, it was so bright! The whole world was a mad, mad, screaming, silent light. Then the noise. One of my ear-drums was shattered
> straight away. I felt the agony, and the hot blood in my ear. Oh, I don’t remember, I don’t remember. I just recall shapes and pain and noises and madness. Falling, falling. My rubber body, being struck, and tossed and pierced. Bang, bang, the rhythm, the side-drum rim-shots, the bus-bouncing juddering. The horror, Oh! Anita, the horror!
>
> [. . . .]
>
> I remember, Dear God, I remember! Your clothes had been burnt away, and you were naked, save for the remains of the little lace pants that I had bought you, which had been burnt into your skin. You were naked, save for the concealing blackness of your blistered flesh. There was a heavy tree branch lying across you, with smoke curling up from it.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> I remember, you bastards! YOU BLEEDING *HUMAN* BASTARDS, I REMEMBER!

Comment: Thank you - that was it - and as moving as I remember